# Parameter meaning of CBasePin::GetMediaType(int iPosition, ...) method

Tags: directshow

Thanks to everyone who views my question.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368709(v=vs.85).aspx

It is not very clear from the documentation regarding the `iPosition` parameter for

```
virtual HRESULT GetMediaType(
  int iPosition,
  CMediaType *pMediaType
);
```

It is said "*Zero-based index value.*", but what kind of index it is?  the index of the samples?

I have a source filter sending the H.264 NALU flows (MEDIASUBTYPE_AVC1) and it works very well except that the SPS/PPS may be changed after the video is played for a while.

The SPS and PPS are appended to the `MPEG2VIDEOINFO` structure, which is passed in `CMediaType::SetFormat` method when `GetMediaType` method is called.

and there is another version of `GetMediaType` which accepts the `iPosition` parameter. It seems I can use this method to update the SPS / PPS.

My question is: **What does the iPosition param mean, and how does Decoder Filter know which SPS/PPS are assigned for each NALU sample.**

```
HRESULT GetMediaType(int iPosition, CMediaType *pMediaType)
{
    ATLTRACE( "\nGetMediaType( iPosition = %d ) ", iPosition);
    CheckPointer(pMediaType,E_POINTER);  
    CAutoLock lock(m_pFilter->pStateLock());

    if (iPosition < 0)
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }
    if (iPosition == 0)
    {
        pMediaType->InitMediaType();
        pMediaType->SetType(&MEDIATYPE_Video); 
        pMediaType->SetFormatType(&FORMAT_MPEG2Video);  
        pMediaType->SetSubtype(&MEDIASUBTYPE_AVC1);
        pMediaType->SetVariableSize();

    }

    int nCurrentSampleID;
    DWORD dwSize = m_pFlvFile->GetVideoFormatBufferSize(nCurrentSampleID);
    LPBYTE pBuffer = pMediaType->ReallocFormatBuffer(dwSize);
    memcpy( pBuffer, m_pFlvFile->GetVideoFormatBuffer(nCurrentSampleID), dwSize);

    pMediaType->SetFormat(pBuffer, dwSize);


    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: The idea is that somebody will enumerate the supported media types by calling you with incrementally increased indices until you return `FALSE` to say that no media types left that you can offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPosition is used to offer different mediatypes, like other resolutions or different encoding or in your exampel maybe a raw h246. If you only offer one type, thats ok, but don't forget to send `VFW_S_NO_MORE_ITEMS` if the iPosition is to high.

The sps/pps changes are send with the mediasamples. You simply [add your new mediatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407019%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the current sample in `FillBuffer`. Some decoders didn't even need that, they just read the sps/pps from the datastream.